ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil_psutil_windows'
I'm trying to upload my python file to create a web apps on streamlit and run into a problem like this
I don't know what cause this problem and how to fix it. I need some advises to find the problem and fix it.
Or i just code everything again?
enter image description here

Please include the error message as text, and not an image. See also [ask]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
